# Rest API authentication for sharepoint 2010

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to authenticate and authorize the rest API call for Sharepoint 2010.
Also please provide a steps for how to authenticate the rest API call using postman rest client.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authorize the rest API with C#, here is a simple demo of retrieving data of list via REST API with C# for your reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// retrieve JSON Data of list via REST API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="webUri"></param>
    /// <param name="credentials"></param>
    /// <param name="listTitle"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JToken GetList(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials, string listTitle)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");
            Uri endpointUri = new Uri(webUri + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')");
            string result = client.DownloadString(endpointUri);

            JObject jo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            JToken jToken = jo["d"];
            return jToken;
        }
    }
```

About credential, we can do as below.

```
 NetworkCredential credentials= new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
```